# Cannot get Request Package to Run in Python via Conda

Tags: conda, setuptools, python-requests-html

I am having problems getting my Requests package to fun in Python via
Conda in VSCODE. When I type in "Conda list" in my Base environment in the terminal I can see the following:

> ```
>     requests                  2.30.0                   pypi_0    pypi
>     requests-file             1.5.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
> ```

I read that I may have to uninstall and reinstall setuptools to rectify this.  I can also see the following listed in my packages:

> ```
> setuptools                61.2.0           py39haa95532_0
> ```

However, I am seeing some unusual error messages when I try to install or uninstall packages or just simply list packages:

> ```
> Error processing line 3 of C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapis_common_protos-1.59.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:
>
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
>       exec(line)
>     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_from_spec
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
>
> Remainder of file ignored
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_distutils_hack\__init__.py:30:
> ```
>
> UserWarning: Setuptools is replacing distutils.

Any idea how to fix this without reinstalling Conda?

> 

Here is some more information on my environment variables:

> ```
> environment variables:
>     CIO_TEST=<not set>
> CONDA_EXE=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
>                    CONDA_EXES="C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe"
>     CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
>     CONDA_ROOT=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
>     CONDA_SHLVL=0
>     CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
>     HOMEPATH=\Users\MyName
>     LD_PRELOAD=<not set>
>                          PATH=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\Program
>                               Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files
>                               (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>                               Files\Oculus\Support\oculus-runtime;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\
>                               WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WI
>                               NDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\WorldPainter;C:\Program
>                               Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>                               Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client
>                               SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.
> ```
>
> ;C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
> Code\bin;C:\Users\MyName.dotnet\tools;
> C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VSCode Insiders\bin
> PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\Windows PowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Windows PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
> REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=
> SSL_CERT_FILE=
>
> ```
>     active environment : None
>     shell level : 0
>     user config file : C:\Users\MyName\.condarc
>     populated config files : C:\Users\MyName\.condarc
>     conda version : 23.3.1
>     conda-build version : 3.24.0
>     python version : 3.9.12.final.0
>     virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
>                               __win=0=0
>     base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (writable)
>         conda av data dir : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\etc\cond
>         conda av metadata url : None`
> ```

Thanks

Comment: I’d expect this has more to do with VSCode’s terminal configuration and environment activation, rather than package installation.

Comment: I am at a bit of a loss here.  What would you recommend for my next step to get this running again.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling `requests` from Conda? One should really never have PyPI packages showing up in the **base** environment. Also, what does `python -c 'import requests; print(requests.__path__)'` show?